# How to pass long or int data type value in MultipartEntity?

Tags: android, web-services, int, form-data

I'm developing web-serviced base app, and my web-service requirement is pass  **int or long** value in form data in parameter. Is it possible or not?

Here is my code:

```
MultipartEntity entity  = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

entity.addPart("key_id", new StringBody("10001")); //pass int or long
```

What should I use instead of `new StringBody("0")`.

Comment: @Dumbo: please don't add "thanks in advice" here. The grammatically correct phrase is "thanks in advance", but we don't do thanks here - if you encounter waffle of this kind, please remove it. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer why you are so rude? Who you are that you don't let people be thankful? So why you are thanking after your comment? :D

Comment: @Dumbo The problem with phrases like "Thanks in advance" are considered as "noisy", because thankfulness can be expressed by users by upvoting answers, and (just fur the OP) by accepting an answer.

Comment: Hi @Dumbo. I am happy to learn from you if I can, but upon re-reading my comment to you, I cannot see any rudeness at all. It is correct, in terms of the remark about grammar - your edit added a mistake into the text, which you would surely want to know about. It is also correct in terms of our editing culture, which aims for a technical standard of writing. See Meta discussions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `MultipartEntity.addPart()` accepts only `StringBody` or `FileBody`.

Anything else has to be converted to `String` and type-casted again in receiver side, in this case `Long/Int`.

Comment: Yes.. PostMan mocks your client request. Receiver has to type-cast the value again.

Answer (score 0):

MultipartEntity only accepts string value or a file in the request body.
File goes in the format with multiple other params like fileName and fileSize.

Also in a simple GET request the params in the url go in the string format which are typecasted on the server side as per the requirement.